# Unable to uninstall kops

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to downgrade my kops version from `1.23.0` to `1.21.5`.

I tried to uninstall kops first, but I got this error:

```
$ kops uninstall kops
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/kops
```

Here are some information about my kops

```
$ kops version
Version 1.23.0 (git-a067cd7742a497a5c512762b9880664d865289f1)

$ type -p kops
kops is /usr/local/bin/kops

$ ls -l $(type -p kops)
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: kops: No such file or directory
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 my_name admin  165095824 Apr 20 13:23 /usr/local/bin/kops

$ ls -l $(which kops)
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 my_name  admin  165095824 Apr 20 13:23 /usr/local/bin/kops
```

I've tried to solve this problem by using similar commands in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225045/no-such-keg-usr-local-cellar-git), but that doesn't work.

Running `brew uninstall --force kops`, and `brew cleanup -s kops` doesn't return any message.

Does anyone know how to solve `No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/kops` error?

My macOS version is `12.5.1`. Its CPU is `2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/kops` is not symlinked, so it doesn't seem to be installed via Homebrew. You need to uninstall it manually (including any additional files/libraries it requires) before installing the prefered version via Homebrew.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.  My `kops` was not installed via Homebrew. It was installed by downloading the `kops` executable file from github and placing it under `/usr/local/bin/`. 
By the way, how do you know that my `/usr/local/bin/kops` is not symlinked?

Comment: @brian Run `ls -l` on a binary in `/usr/local/bin` which *is* installed via Homebrew to see the difference :-)